# Disable screen auto-rotate on iPhone XS Max

Tags: iphone, ios

How to disable automatic screen rotate on iPhone XS Max ?

I'm not finding that option to disable it in the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

Steps :

1. From the top, do left swipe to open **Control Center**.
2. Then, there is an option **Portait Orientation Lock**.
3. Tap on that to make it **On**. That's all, the screen is locked.

Screenshot :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If swiping up on the control center then maybe you might be in the same situation as [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8546976) person.